# How to get a subset of map from another map based on a list of keys? C++

Tags: c++, dictionary, stdmap

I have an old map sample:

```
map<string, int> map_ = {"A": 1, "B": 2, "C": 3, "D": 4, "E": 5}
```

and a list of keys:

```
vector<string> list_ = {"B", "D", "E"}
```

I want to get a new map from the old one based on the key list:

```
map<string, int> mapNew_ = {"B": 2, "D": 4, "E": 5}
```

Is there any smart way to do this?

Comment: What would you consider to be a "dumb" way to do this?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Take each element out and create a value list, then build a new map from the value list and key list

Comment: Umm.. What is a "value list"?  Those terms are not the usual C++ terminology.  The simple way is the answer given by @NathanOliver.  It looks like you may have overthought how to accomplish this, based on some other computer language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with a simple ranged based for loop.  That would look like

```
map<string, int> mapNew_;
for (const auto& e : list_)
    mapNew_[e] = map_[e];
```

If `list_` could contain elements that are not in the map, then you would need to add a check for that like

```
map<string, int> mapNew_;
for (const auto& e : list_)
    if (auto it = map.find(e); it != map.end())
        mapNew_[e] = it->second; // no map_[e] here since it already points to the needed value
```

Comment: Of course, the only issue is if `list_` contains values that are not in `map_`.

Comment: Ah this is neat! Thank you so much!

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Good call.  Added a version to handle if that is the case.

Comment: @Cyan No problem.  I also added a version that will handle if `list_` has values that aren't in the original map.

Comment: @NathanOliver I also notice the element order of the new map would be reversed like `{"E": 5, "D": 4, "B": 2}`.

Comment: @Cyan [`std::map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) is a sorted container. It sorts its keys using `operator<` by default, so in this case it is using [`std::string::operator<`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_cmp) which will not put `"E"` before `"D"`, or `"D"` before `"B"`, etc. Perhaps you are simply *displaying* the map in reverse order?

Comment: @NathanOliver you are right! I actually want the order to be consistent with the list. For instance, if my list is `{"E", "B", "D"}`, then I want the new map to be `{"E": 5, "B": 2, "D": 4}`. Sorry for missing that part.

Comment: @Cyan Both maps should have the same order, they do here: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6663f95baa69b7bf

Comment: @Cyan That isn't really something you can have.  `map` stores it's elements in an sorted manner.

Comment: @Cyan "*I actually want the order to be consistent with the list*" - You can't accomplish that kind of ordering with a `std::map` (well, not without a custom comparator, anyway). In this case, you should use a `std::vector<std::pair<std::string, int>>` instead, then you can add items to it in whatever order you want.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Got it! Right I just realized I don't need to care about the order. Thank you both!